# How to calculate the variance and expected value of a random variable with density function f(x) in R

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics

was wondering how to calculate the expected value and variance of some function f(x).

For the Expected value $\mu,$ I integrated x*f(x) and I'm confident that is correct, but I'm confused about how to calculate the variance using integrals and f(x).

I was wondering if I should use: This Formula for Variance
$Var(X) = E(X^2) - \mu^2.$

where I would set a variable to the value of the expected value I found earlier and use that formula.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you want the mean $\mu_X = E(X)$ of random variable $X$ with density function $f_X(x).$ Then $E(X) = \int_S xf_X(x)\,dx,$ where $S$ is the support of $X,$ that is the set of values $x$ such that $f_X(x) > 0.$ Your equation for variance is missing. It should be $\sigma_X^2 = Var(X) = \int_S (x - \mu)^2f_X(x) \, dx.$ Also, $Var(X) = \int_S x^2f_X(x)\,dx - \mu_X^2.$

Answer (score 2):

*Example:* If $X \sim \mathsf{Beta}(2,1)$, which has density function $f_X(x) = 2x,$ for $0 < x < 1$ and $0$ elsewhere. [See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) on beta distributions.]

Then
$$\mu_X = E(X) = \int_0^1 xf_X(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 x(2x)\,dx\\
=\int_0^1 2x^2\,dx = 2/3.$$
Also,
$$\sigma_X^2=Var(X) = E(X^2) - \mu_X^2 = \int_0^1 x^2f_X(x)\,dx - (2/3)^2\\ = \int_0^1 2x^3\, dx - (2/3)^2
=1/2 - (2/3)^2 = 1/18.$$

Maybe you can practice with the first formula for $Var(X).$

Approximation by simulation in R for reality check (to a couple of decimal places of accuracy):

```
set.seed(2020)  # for reproducibility
x = rbeta(10^6, 2, 1)
mean(x)
[1] 0.6665343   # aprx E(X) = 2/3
var(x)
[1] 0.05551495  # aprx Var(X) = 1/18
1/18
[1] 0.05555556
```

*Note:* There is a numerical integration procedure in R, where `dbeta` is the PDF
of a beta distribution. Here is a rudimentary introduction for
finding $E(X) = 2/3$ and $E(X^2)=1/2.$

```
integrand1 = function(x){x*dbeta(x,2,1)}
integrate(integrand1, 0, 1)
0.6666667 with absolute error < 7.4e-15

integrand2 = function(x)(x^2*dbeta(x,2,1))
integrate(integrand2,0,1)
0.5 with absolute error < 5.6e-15
```

Comment: This numerical approach to the variance should be deprecated, because it will drastically lose accuracy for any distribution with a small CV.  Instead, first compute $\mu$ and then integrate $(x-\mu)^2f(x)\mathrm{d}x.$ Finally, having obtained a rough estimate of the variance, use that to narrow the range of integration and redo the integration to improve the accuracy and precision.

Comment: @whuber. Are you referring to `integrate` in the note? Or also to the simulation? OP specifically asked about using R, or I would just have left it at showing the calculus.

Comment: I am also referring to the formula that follows your "also." The integration will be faster and more accurate using the formula in my comment. It's also wise to invoke `integrate` to compute the integral of $f$ itself. This accomplishes several things: (a) it enables you to normalize an unnormalized $f$ as a convenience to the user; (b) in many cases an error in finding the moments can nearly be canceled by a comparable (relative) error in integrating $f,$ thereby increasing accuracy; and (c) as an indicator of problems (if you are expecting a normalized $f$) when the value isn't near $1.$

Comment: Just to make sure everyone knows we're talking about errors in _numerical_ integration, I'll mention that the two formulas are identical in calculus: Abbreviating notation for Comment: $Var(X)=\int (x-\mu)^2f(x)dx=\int[x^2-2\mu x +\mu^2]f(x)dx$ $=\int x^2f(x)dx-2\mu\int xf(x)dx +\mu^2\int f(x)dx = E(X^2)-2\mu^2+\mu^2$ $=E(X^2)-\mu^2.$