# How to calculate variance and expected value in R given some function f(x)

Tags: r, variance

I was wondering how to calculate the expected value and variance of some function f(x).

For the Expected value, I integrated x*f(x) and I'm confident that is correct, but I'm confused about how to calculate the variance using integrals and f(x).

I was wondering if I should use:
[This Formula for Variance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRaiy.png)

where I would set a variable to the value of the expected value I found earlier and use that formula.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You already asked this 30 minutes ago, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482617/how-to-calculate-the-variance-and-expected-value-of-a-function-fx-in-r)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the variance and expected value of a function f(x) in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482617/how-to-calculate-the-variance-and-expected-value-of-a-function-fx-in-r)